# Silent Synchronization using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to implement a silent synchronization with GCM?
I implemented a small messaging functionality which works really good with GCM.
I would also like to synchronize configurations using GCM but i dont need
a push message or anything like it for it.

I simply want to update the shared preferences of my app when the server side
configuration got changed and i also want to send the app configuration silently
to the server when the app configuration changed.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already done the messaging part, it all goes the same way, use the same path and methods that you use for the messaging to send the configuration parsed in a way that you can read on both sides.

Ex. in the title of the GCM message add a configuration tag to identify it as configuration broadcast like ("APP_SYNC").
In the message part add the parameters splited as you see fit like ("INTERVAL:50 , IP:192.202.2.2")

- if the question about silently is that you want all this done in the background without the need to launch the app, then dont worry, you can do anything from the background (change shared pref, add to sqllite or anything) from your GCM receiver's code.

I think you got the point.